# Check difference between results not listed and identify which day is the date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    V.CHAPA,
    F.NOME,
    V.DATA,
    MAX(V.SEQUENCIALBATIDA) AS BATIDA
      FROM
            ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW AS V
            LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC  AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
        WHERE
            V.CHAPA = 9132
        AND BATIDA IS NOT NULL 
        AND V.CODCOLIGADA = 1 
        AND  YEAR ( V.DATA ) = 2016 
        AND MONTH ( V.DATA ) = 9
         GROUP BY V.CHAPA,
                  F.NOME,
                  V.DATA 
          ORDER BY V.DATA ASC
```

It returns me:

```
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-02 00:00:00.000 4
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-03 00:00:00.000 4
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-04 00:00:00.000 2
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-05 00:00:00.000 4
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-06 00:00:00.000 4

>>> 1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-07 00:00:00.000 2
>>> 1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-09 00:00:00.000 4

1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-10 00:00:00.000 4
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-11 00:00:00.000 2
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-12 00:00:00.000 4
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-13 00:00:00.000 4

>>> 1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-14 00:00:00.000 4
>>> 1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-16 00:00:00.000 4
```

As you can see in places marked with >>> there is no record that date, eg the date jumps 7 to 9 date and the date 14 jumps to 16, it ta correct because that day had no change.

What do I need to know: How many ente day on 08 and 15 which are the days that has no movement because this period can not exceed 7 days.

Another vestment I need is: At the same query:

```
SELECT 
    V.CHAPA,
    F.NOME,
    V.DATA,
    MAX(V.SEQUENCIALBATIDA) AS BATIDA
      FROM
            ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW AS V
            LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC  AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
        WHERE
            V.CHAPA = 9132
        AND BATIDA IS NOT NULL 
        AND V.CODCOLIGADA = 1 
        AND  YEAR ( V.DATA ) = 2016 
        AND MONTH ( V.DATA ) = 9
         GROUP BY V.CHAPA,
                  F.NOME,
                  V.DATA 
          ORDER BY V.DATA ASC
```

I need to identify what day of the week is the date, and list only Sunday.

How could proceed with these two cases?

> Note: I'm sorry if you have any clerical error and because I am not
>   good at English and used a translator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my answer to the following question on StackOverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093924/select-all-months-within-given-date-span-including-the-ones-with-0-values/3111441#3111441

You could easily apply this method to your problem, and return data for all the days between a range, including those with no data content.

Dave